# listview not update after swipe to delete from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am using swipe to delete in android listview. its removed from the database but not update in the listview when i refresh the button then it will updated, but i want update quickly after swipe to delete.

dbhelper.java

```
public void deleteInterestId(DesignItems designItems) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " where " + KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID + " = '" + designItems.getNotificationId() + "'");
    db.close();

}
```

main.java

```
  SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    notificationList,
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {

                                final DesignItems m = designItemsList.get(position);
                                DesignItems designItems = new DesignItems();

                                designItems.setNotificationId(m.getNotificationId());
                                dbHelper.deleteInterestId(designItems);

                                designItemsList.remove(position);

                                list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }

                        }
                    });
    notificationList.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

so most good solutions welcome.

Comment: 1. make changes in the same list that you have provided to adapter. 2. Run the notifydatadsetchanged method in runOnUiThread method

Comment: u mean??     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
        }